# Is an array of digits an efficient way to create numbers too long for the default variable types?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is already a question on how to create extra-large numbers of that I can roughly remember what it said (I couldn't find the original thread, but it is on StackOverflow). The recommendation that stuck to me the most was the one that said to use a linked list, a type of structure, for using numbers that are too large. But, I was having so much trouble actually using it that I just made a short int array of digits. My friend, who I consider a better programmer than me, also told me that ***linked lists are the way to go, but I do not see what is wrong with the array system.***

Here is the actual code ***(not that important but just in case)***

It's a script that calculates factorial, I needed the extra digits because factorials get too big too fast.

[image of new code in action with cout statements on each calculation
thanks @TonkK and @ n. 'pronouns' m. for being nice to my amateur coder brain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJK2q.png)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void factorial(int n, int s = 100)
{
    cout << "number: ";
    //establish return array
    short int x[s] = {1};
    short int a[s];
    //for every number from 2 (1 include previously) to n
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            x[j] *= i;
            a[j] = x[j];
        }

        for (int j = s - 1; j >= 1; j--)
        {
            x[j] = a[j - 1] / 10 + a[j] % 10;
            if (x[j] > 9)
            {
                x[j + 1] += x[j] / 10;
                x[j] = x[j] % 10;
            }
        }

        x[0] %= 10;

        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            if (x[j] > 9)
            {
                x[j + 1] += x[j] / 10;
                x[j] = x[j] % 10;
            }
        }
    }

    //flip array
    int start = 0;
    int end = s - 1;
    while (start < end) 
    { 
        int temp = x[start];  
        x[start] = x[end]; 
        x[end] = temp; 
        start++; 
        end--; 
    }

    //remove unnecesary zeroes
    int flag = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] == 0)
            flag = i;
        else
            break;
    }
    for (int i = flag + 1; i < s; i++)
    {
        cout << x[i];
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int s;
    cout << "type in a number\t";
    cin >> n;
    //get s based off n
    int dn = double(n);
    s = 0.007 * (dn * dn) + 0.94 * dn + 1;
    cout << "digits: " << s << "\n";
    factorial(n, s);
}
```

Comment: (1) A linked list is almost always the least efficient option available. (2) You need to be aware that your program is not standard C++ because C++ doesn't have variable length arrays, so declarations like `short int x[s] = {1};` are illegal. (3) Calculations in base 10 are suboptimal. Computers are binary for a reason.

Comment: I can't see how linked lists would be useful. Perhaps you could supply a link to the question? In any case, your method is perfectly suitable for numbers of a few tens of digits. As a simple optimisation, working in base 100 would be four times faster (or base 10000 would be 16 times faster, if your `short` is 32 bits).

Comment: TonyK, how would I make base 100? If I declare a variable as short short int it registers as short int instead, and compiles with the error duplicate 'short'.

Comment: And if your `short` is 32 bits, then base 65536 is even better, as @n.'pronouns'm. implies. Going to base ‭4294967296‬ is faster, but then you need to use 64-bit arithmetic (or assembly language) to handle the multiplications.

Comment: n. 'pronouns' m. thank you for the advice. I'll look more into base 2 operations in the future and converting back and forth for human use.

Comment: Pablo, I don't understand your question. Just declare your array as before, but interpret its elements as base-100 digits instead of base-10 digits. In your code, replace 10 by 100 and 9 by 99. (And your output step needs to add a leading '0' to base-100 digits less than 10.)

Comment: Pablo: no! base 2 is even slower than base 10. @n.'pronouns'm. means to use base 2^n for some n.

Comment: To both of these messages, sorry for the misunderstanding, and I can try and implement both of these bits of advice right away now that I understand them more.

Comment: @TonyK, Choice of base depends on what you want to do. If you need bitwise operations, then it's surely a way to go. But on the other hand, conversion from binary to decimal (eg for printing) can become a problem (I had this experience with Java's BigInteger). For multiplication/addition the choice of 2^n or 10^m doesn't matter much.

Comment: You will have to convert your number back to decimal on output. Perhaps using base 10^m would be easier at first. But definitely try 2^k base too.

Comment: Have a look at [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @Dmitry: for addition, I agree. For multiplication, the choice of base certainly matters. But you are right: there is a trade-off between speed of multiplication and simplicity of output.